# How to invalidate Forms control continously without interfere with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, repaint, invalidation

I have a Control that is in a `WindowsFormsHost`. This control is for drawing content in an OpenGL context and need to be invalidated after every draw.

The problem: WPF Controls are not reacting anymore, if I do that. You can click on them and they work, but you do not get any visual feedback like when you hover over it or press the WPF button. The button does not change the color or something it normaly does, if you hover over it.

I created a little repro for you:

### XAML

```
<Grid>
  <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="uxContainerWindowsFormsHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" Margin="101,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
  <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

### Code

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var b = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        b.Text = "Button";
        b.Paint += b_Paint;

        uxContainerWindowsFormsHost.Child = b;
    }

    void b_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button).Invalidate();
    }
```

If you click on the WPF button, you will not get any visual feedback that you clicked on the button.

### Question

How can I use a continous invalidation in my `WindowsFormsHost` like in the repro, without loosing the visual feedback on my buttons?

Comment: My guess, you are using up 100% of the UI thread. Try using Application.DoEvents() or invalidating the WinForms control less often (e.g. throttling in a timer loop). Another idea, is you can invalidate the WinForms OpenGL control inside the CompositionTarget.Rendering event, which occurs when WPF draws to the screen. This ensures your redraws in WinForms do not occur faster than WPF can draw.

Comment: The real question is why you need to invalidate the control after every draw? That shouldn't be necessary and it is an indication of a design error within the control.

Comment: @RedSerpent My control should be updated at least 60 times per second to get a smooth framerate. Maybe I can limit it to this instead of drawing it as fast as possible. But I would prefer to render the images as fast as possible.

Comment: @Dr.ABT I tested your ideas: DoEvents() make my application freeze after a short time. But CompositionTarget.Rendering works. I'm not sure now if I loose the advantage of using OpenGL instead of WPF 3D... I hope not :)

Comment: It's all rendering pumps. I develop a charting library - http://www.scichart.com and we successfully trigger DirectX11 drawing inside CompositionTarget.Rendering and it works well. We use throttling. We only redraw the DX surface if something changed (mouse-drag, or model change) *and* the CompositionTarget event has fired. Just be sure to *unsubscribe* because CompositionTarget.Rendering event handler can cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event that Dr. ABT showed in the comment.

```
Constructor()
{
  CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
}

void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _myControl.Invalidate();
}
```